# DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()

Tags: entity-framework-core, xunit2

I am studying packtpub's entity framework core cookbook on unit test, there is an example (I made some change)

```
[Fact]
public void CanCreateDatabase()
{
    var blogContext = new BlogContext(_builder.Options);

    var created = blogContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

    Assert.True(created);
}

[Fact]
public void CanRetrieveRecord()
{
    var blogContext = new BlogContext(_builder.Options);

    var blog1 = blogContext.Blogs.FirstOrDefault();

    Assert.Contains("Development", blog1.Name);
}
```

The first test fail, the second pass. I am pretty sure the database has been created, that is why the second test passed, but why the first test fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on documentation of `EnsureCreated` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_EnsureCreated)

> Returns
>   System.Boolean
>   True if the database is created, false if it already existed.

In above tests, assuming there is no database present, for the first test run, `EnsureCreated` will create the database and pass the tests. But for any subsequent run, the database is already present hence `EnsureCreated` returns false. Perhaps you want to use `EnsureDeleted` before `EnsureCreated` to make sure that database is dropped so that you can test its actually being created.